# Can we integrate Flutter pages into Hugo

Tags: html, flutter, hugo, static-site-generation

Looking to integrate specific flutter pages and stateful widgets in Hugo. If we can't do specific widgets then how to include the whole application.

I have referred to this flutter code but how can we implement it in Hugo.

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'package:js/js_util.dart' as js_util;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

enum DemoScreen { counter, textField, custom }

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

@js.JSExport()
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _streamController = StreamController<void>.broadcast();
  DemoScreen _currentDemoScreen = DemoScreen.counter;
  int _counterScreenCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final export = js_util.createDartExport(this);
    js_util.setProperty(js_util.globalThis, '_appState', export);
    js_util.callMethod<void>(js_util.globalThis, '_stateSet', []);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @js.JSExport()
  void increment() {
      setState(() {
        _counterScreenCount++;
        _streamController.add(null);
      });
  }

  @js.JSExport()
  void addHandler(void Function() handler) {
    _streamController.stream.listen((event) {
      handler();
    });
  }

  @js.JSExport()
  int get count => _counterScreenCount;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Element embedding',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: CounterDemo(
          title: 'Counter',
          numToDisplay: _counterScreenCount,
          incrementHandler: increment,
        ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int numToDisplay;
  final VoidCallback incrementHandler;

  const CounterDemo({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.numToDisplay,
    required this.incrementHandler,
  });

  @override
  State<CounterDemo> createState() => _CounterDemoState();
}

class _CounterDemoState extends State<CounterDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${widget.numToDisplay}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: widget.incrementHandler,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There is a web embedding sample for Angular here. https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/web_embedding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78059539/can-we-integrate-flutter-pages-into-hugo